# How to show complex object properties from an API call in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

So I've been working on making a Recipe App on react. I've taken data for this app from https://www.themealdb.com/api.php on this site. I've been able to show Meal Names by search and also if I want to specific details about a meal I've been also able to do it but in this API there's a complex piece of data which show all the ingredients and measurement. I've tried for a long time but couldn't able show the measurements and ingredients of the meal. I am attaching the response of the ingredients and measurements.[image: Ingredients] [image: Measure]

As you can see there are null values in both Ingredients and Measure. I can show both of these if I call them by numbers for ex - strIngredient1,strIngredient2, and so on. What I want I do is I will take all the Ingredients and Measure and whenever there is a null or empty string it will not show it in the details of a specific meal. How can I do it using React Hooks?

Comment: Please post a small sample data as **text** that people can work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with React.

You can test for a truthy (something that resolves to true) in JS with the following:

`if (x) { }`

Empty strings will not get into that, neither will `undefined` or `null`. Just check each value to see if you should add it to the UI and you'll be good.

Comment: A thing that is specific to React is that this is usually done with expressions in JSX, i.e. ternary or short circuit ops.

Comment: That's just JS. All scripting within JSX is. It all boils down to a truthy check.

Comment: Useful "table", just in case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy. Also worth to check links in "See also" section.